# How to fetch values of a drop down box with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, css-selectors, casperjs

I was looking in several threads about retrieving values from a drop down box to use the values for a later time in the casperjs script.

So my issue is that I can't fetch the values from my drop down box and actually use it in my next step, for now just to echo it out.

This is how my drop down box looks in my web page:
[image]

I did tried some examples but it just doesn't work, what am I doing wrong?

```
casper.then(function() {
    var options = this.evaluate(function() {
        var options = document.getElementById('selectedNetworkElementOrGroup_TD').children;
        return [].map.call(options, function(opt) {
            return { val: opt.value, text: opt.textContent };
        });
    });
    this.echo(JSON.stringify(options));
});
```

One problem could be that the drop down box has no id!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a basic CSS selector like this one: `#selectedNetworkElementOrGroup_TR select`:

```
var options = this.evaluate(function() {
    var options = document.querySelector('#selectedNetworkElementOrGroup_TR select').children;
    return [].map.call(options, function(opt) {
        return { val: opt.value, text: opt.textContent };
    });
});
this.echo(JSON.stringify(options));
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply, but the echo gives me _null_ as output? Any clue why?

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I forgot to change the standard `getElementById()` call to `querySelector()` when I copied your code.